# Google JavaScript API's with phonegap

Tags: cordova, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm using Google JavaScript API's SDK for a Google Drive web application. I want to convert this to a native app for iOS using phonegap. What Javascript origins should I specify in the API's console.

Comment: did you get this to work/